# "Bad message" when trying to access a directory on external hard drive

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, hard-drive, filesystem, data-transfer

I'm running a media server using a Raspberry Pi 4 with an external hard drive connected via USB 3.0.

One issue I've been seeing for a while is "Bad message" returned when I try to `ls` or `stat` inside a certain directory inside my (ext4 formatted) external hard drive.

[image: Bad message]

---

The odd thing is that restarting the system appears to fix the issue 100% of the time I see it occur (I also don't have the `fsck` value set in fstab for the drive, so I don't believe it's being run on boot for that drive).

[image: Working after reboot]

Also, I even went as far as to repair the filesystem and even *swap out the entire disk itself with a new one* (using the same enclosure), format it again, and am still seeing the issue!

I'm aware of [the Pi 4's issues with USB 3 and UASP](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=245931&sid=b2d634343632113c94a01b812e1db1ce) and have already enabled "quirks mode" for the enclosure (my /boot/cmdline.txt: `usb-storage.quirks=152d:0578:u,152d:1561:u console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=d4b5ead6-01 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait`).

I'm running some Docker containers that all use the hard drive (Radarr, Sonarr, etc.). Could this be due to a process keeping a file handle open? A corrupted file being downloaded somewhere inside?

Or is this really just some kind of core issue with the Pi 4, [as this commenter seems to think](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=245931&sid=4e133360c3bd6d080fac48fe36abea5b&start=225#p1849533)?

Thanks for any help. I'm a bit stumped and this has been annoying me for months now.

Comment: you say *inside a **certain** directory* ... is it **any** directory in the USB drive, or that particular one?

Comment: Just a particular directory (although it is the one most likely written to recently) but other directories that don't have much writes on the drive seem to be accessible without any issue!